# message partitioner when using dependency injection?

Tags: c#, masstransit

How can I setup message partitioning when registering consumer via dependency injection (autofac), like so

```
 cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, c =>
                    {
                        c.LoadFrom(context);
                        c.Durable = true;
                    });
```

All messages are of the same marker interface

```
 IDomainEvent<Guid>
```

I want all messages to be partitioned by the Id property of that interface.

I'm thinking of trying something like this:

```
 c.Consumer<SomeViewConsumer>(context,ConfigurePartition<SomeViewConsumer>(partitioner));
 c.Consumer<SomeOtherViewConsumer>(context,ConfigurePartition<SomeOtherViewConsumer>(partitioner));


  private static Action<IConsumerConfigurator<TConsumer>> ConfigurePartition<TConsumer>(IPartitioner partitioner) where TConsumer : class
  {
        return n => n.Message<IDomainEvent<Guid>>(k => k.UsePartitioner(partitioner, consumeContext => consumeContext.Message.Id));
  }
```

Would this work?

Comment: That would work, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an automatic way to do it, since the message type must be known to configure the partitioner delegate which returns the partition key.

I'd also be concerned about consuming too many different messages types on a single receive endpoint, by pulling them automatically from the container using `.LoadFrom()`.

Comment: I changed the question a bit. Would it work that way?